# Set a system property with ant

Tags: ant, system-properties

I have an ant script which has a `taskdef` and the task creates an https internet connection and somethin with that SSL stuff is wrong. Thus I want to set the system property `javax.net.debug=all` to get some more information.

In java I would do this using the `-D` option, but in ant this is used for ant properties which is not the same as a system property.

If this wouldn't be a `taskdef` but instead a [`java`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task, I could use the `sysproperty` property, but it is no `java`-task.

Googling for this is frustratingly complicated because ant properties and system properties in ant are so similar that most search results are about the other (or about the `java`-task).

Obviously I am not the only one with the problem, but other people's questions that I have found ([like here](http://osdir.com/ml/user-ant-apache/2009-07/msg00294.html)) are unanswered or went for hack (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748135/setting-sys-properties-in-ant-taskdef)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to set such a property is the `ANT_OPTS` system variable. You have to be very carefully to not simply skim over answers on google that state that options can be set that way, because it sounds so much like not what it does:

The [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) says:

> ANT_OPTS - command-line arguments that should be passed to the JVM.
>   For example, you can define system properties or set the maximum Java
>   heap size here.

Who what have expected that? ANT_OPTS are options for the JVM and not for ant like the name suggests. The var which is used for ant options is called `ANT_ARGS`.

Now I can launch ant like this: `ANT_OPTS="-Djavax.net.debug=all" ant myTarget` and can see tons of log output.

(However this leaves the question open whether such a variable can be set using XML).

Comment: Thanks, this info helpeld me a lot as I tried to figure out why jenkins takes a "wrong" value if defined it in _Build -> Invoke Ant -> Properties_ e.g. `user.name = prod`. When defined in _Java Options_ (uses ANT_OPS) as `-Duser.name=prod` everything works expected. System property user.name got's overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare system properties in the xml with `<sysproperty key="key" value="value"/>`.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Ant/SetsystempropertiesinAntbuildscript.htm

Comment: This can only be used on java tasks. See the third paragraph in my question which states: "If this wouldn't be a taskdef but instead a java task, I could use the sysproperty property, but it is no java-task."

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripting:

```xml
<script language="javascript">      
    java.lang.System.setProperty('myKey', 'myValue');
</script>
```